# Nuxt error in ./.nuxt/client.js | this.setDynamic is not a function

Tags: nuxt.js, vuepress

[image]

I can not understand what caused this error and whether it is related to my code.

nuxt v1.4.2, windows 10

Can you please tell what could cause this error?

Comment: Having the same problem after switching to nuxt-edge, but I don't have vuepress installed at all. The problem persists even when I reduce my `nuxt.config.js` to a minimum...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very strange, but after removing package `vuepress`, it all worked

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after updating from `1.4.2` to `2.1.0` today. It affected my static generation, not my local dev instance, but maybe this will help: to resolve it, I simply removed my `.nuxt` and `dist` directories and ran `nuxt generate` again.

Answer (score 0):

Switched from `yarn install` to `npm install` and worked for me.