# Nuxt custom module hooks not called

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I want to pass some extra data from the ssr server that's present after the middleware has run, and use that on client side middleware. A bit similar to what nuxt already does with vuex.

[Documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/internals-renderer) at the `render:context` hook:

> Every time a route is server-rendered and before render:route hook. Called before serializing Nuxt context into window.__NUXT__, useful to add some data that you can fetch on client-side.

Now my custom plugin defines some hooks as stated in the documentation, but not all seem to be called properly:

```
module.exports = function() {
  this.nuxt.hook('render:route', (url, result, context) => {
    console.log('This one is called on every server side rendering')
  }

  this.nuxt.hook('renderer', renderer => {
    console.log('This is never called')
  }

  this.nuxt.hook('render:context', context => {
    console.log('This is only called once, when it starts loading the module')
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I pass custom ssr data to the client side renderer?

Comment: Which nuxt version do you use?

Comment: I'm using 1.4.0

Comment: Just for the sake of testing, could You try this in a minimal example with `nuxt-edge`?

Comment: I tried, but I keep getting the same error as state here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716353

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, just found the solution to the core problem of **passing custom data from the (ssr) server to the client**:

Create a plugin: `plugins/my-plugin.js`

```
export default ({ beforeNuxtRender, nuxtState }) => {
  if (process.server) {
    beforeNuxtRender(({ nuxtState }) => {
      nuxtState.myCustomData = true
    })
  } else {
    console.log('My cystom data on the client side:', nuxtState.myCustomData)
  }
}
```

Then register the plugin in your `nuxt.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ['~/plugins/my-plugin']
}
```

Docs [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context).